# Draw many of the same object quickly in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

So I'm working on a game and I need to draw a lot of the same object. Same shape, same size, same color, just different locations.

Right now my setup is like this.

I have some class `Renderer` where object that want to draw on the screen can call `static void addVertex(float x, float y, float z);` which will store the vertex into an `std::vector`. When everyone is done drawing `static void draw();` in `Renderer` is called where everything is stuffed into a VBO and drawn onto the screen.

draw looks like this:

```
void Renderer::draw() {
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, _quadID);
    glBufferSubDataARB(GL_QUADS, 0, _vertexBuffer.dataSize(), _vertexBuffer.toArray());

    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, _colorBuffer.toArray());

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer.toArray());

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, (_vertexBuffer.size() / 3));
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

    _vertexBuffer.clear();
    _colorBuffer.clear();
}
```

Where `_vertexBuffer` and `_colorBuffer` are of a class `template <class T> Buffer` which is more or less a managed `std::vector<T>` for my purposes.

With this setup I can get about 300 things on screen before I start slowing down. Right now everything is a GL_QUAD. Bear in mind I'm a little new to OpenGL, if the above is embarrassing I'm sorry.

How can I improve this to account for like polygons?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On ~modern hardware, [instancing](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Instancing) is the way to go.

The idea is that you send the geometry to your GPU once (one draw call), specifying how many instances you want to draw (`primCount` parameter).

Then in the vertex shader you can use the intrinsic input variable `gl_InstanceID` to learn which instance is being rendered and then use the appropriate transformation for it. This approach implies that you should have the transformations for all your instances available in the vertex shader, for example in an [Uniform Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object).

Edit: The [`glVertexAttribDivisor`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribDivisor.xml) function is very useful together with instancing; it basically allows to have some per-vertex attributes together with some per-instance attributes.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely try it out! I saw a little about this while I was researching.

Comment: [This](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.it/2013/04/there-must-be-50-ways-to-draw-your.html) can be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

There's beautiful thing in OpenGL, called [Display list](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_displaylist.html). NeHe production has [tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/display_lists/15003/) on them which should provide all necessary info and examples. But basically:

```
GLuint displayList; // This should be class attribute
displayList = glGenLists(1);    
glNewList(displayList,GL_COMPILE);
Renderer::draw();
glEndList();
```

And in real draw method just:

```
glCallList( displayList);
```

Don't forget to actualize precompiled display list each time you add/remove something.

Comment: Display list? Ooold :(, deprecated in modern OpenGL. Sometimes useful tho

Comment: @Kos heh, I didn't know it's deprecated :-/// is there any alternative? Or something like that?

Comment: They have been removed somewhere in OpenGL 3.x, but are still available in compatibility profile if you really need them. Still, they probably aren't the best way to use the hardware, i.e. in this case you still need one draw call per every object.

Comment: @Kos I used ogl mostly for school project (and when I was 16 and was programming instead of getting girl friend :D)... In 2.0 it was quite the way to go... And what we've tested on Bezier's surfaces it still is.

Comment: @Vyktor: This situation's really pretty simple: with a good implementation of OpenGL, a display list was, and remains, a good way to do things. "Modern" OpenGL demands that the developer do 5 times as much work to make up for the fact that the people writing some OpenGL implementations couldn't code their way out of a wet paper bag...

Comment: @Vyktor You can generate beziers in a geometry shader nowadays :-).

Comment: @JerryCoffin care to elaborate? Display lists never allowed you to write *less* code than otherwise, since you'd just write the same code between glNewList/glEndList. OTOH the API cleanup in 3.x resulted in OpenGL being both more powerful and more flexible, a win-win.

Comment: @Kos tell that to our professor .) anyway calculating Bezier's points was pleasant in comparison to doing RSA on paper :)

Comment: @Kos: A display list is a lot less work than a VBO, which is essentially all that's available to "replace" it (and yes, a display list does usually use less code, and in a good implementation is just as fast). While there was certainly *some* "cleanup" done (e.g., getting rid of indexed color modes), but a lot of the rest just shifted the burden from OpenGL to the user. This gained nothing in the way of power or flexibility.

Comment: A VBO is nothing more than `memcpy` with a ribbon on top, hard to even talk about any "burden" here. Each major OpenGL version introduces a new, gradually more programmable pipeline, and the whole point of this concept is flexibility.

Comment: @Kos: Shaders were added before OpenGL 3.x. Removing (for one example) the matrix "stuff" did nothing to enable shaders, improve flexibility, etc. Removing (for another example) GL_QUAD, didn't improve anything either -- but it does increase the bandwidth needed to get extra points to the GPU. The burden of code *using* a VBO is much higher than code using a display list.

Comment: In the most efficient cases VBO's will always outperform CallLists, I've gotten 800% improvements in rendering and my CallList code was as efficient as it could be... Yes it took a little while to get used to VBOs but once I made an OO wrapper around it, it's cake now.